# How to change textContent of TextNode in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-8

`textNode.innerHTML = 'abc'` and `textNode.textContent = 'abc'` do not appear to work in IE8. Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974773(v=vs.85).aspx), `textContent` only works in IE9+.

So how can I change the text of a `TextNode` in IE8?

To be clear, I'm talking about an HTML node with [`nodeType === 3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534191(v=vs.85).aspx), I do not want nor care about changing the text of an HTML *element*.

Comment: @Knu Tried that too actually. Doesn't work. I believe `innerText` is for *elements* only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`textNode.nodeValue = 'abc'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) should work fine.

Comment: That appears to work. MSDN said "You cannot use expressions to change the nodeValue of a TextNode object" so I thought it was read-only. Will accept in ~8 minutes.

Comment: Mmh, I don't understand what they mean by that. However, the example actually shows changing the value by assigning to `nodeValue`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534192(v=vs.85).aspx .